# Recyclerview onclick show wrong data after do search and filtering

Tags: java, android

I tried to make recyclerview with lot data using edit text as searchview. It also show data when the item is clicked. But when i try to search data and click it, it gives wrong data or position. Even i already delete the word that i search it keep give wrong data.

This is my main adapter

```
    public class AllBlockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItemArrayList;
        Context context;

        public static class AllBlockViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView imageView;
            public TextView textView1;
            public TextView textView2;

            private View itemView;

            ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItems = new ArrayList<AllBlockItem>();
            Context context;

            public AllBlockViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItems) {
                super(itemView);
                this.allBlockItems = allBlockItems;
                this.context = context;
this.itemView = itemView;

                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blockImage);
                textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blockTitle);
                textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blockRecipe);
            }
        }

        public AllBlockAdapter(ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItems, Context context1) {
            allBlockItemArrayList = allBlockItems;
            context = context1;
        }

        @Override
        public AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.allblock_item, parent, false);
            AllBlockViewHolder allBlockViewHolder = new AllBlockViewHolder(view, context, allBlockItemArrayList);
            return allBlockViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder holder, int position) {
            AllBlockItem currentItem = allBlockItemArrayList.get(position);

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
            holder.textView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
            holder.textView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

                        AllBlockItem allBlockItem = holder.allBlockItems.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AllBlockDetail.class);
                        intent.putExtra("mImageResource", allBlockItem.getImageResource());
                        intent.putExtra("mText1", allBlockItem.getText1());
                        intent.putExtra("mText2", allBlockItem.getText2());

                        this.context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return allBlockItemArrayList.size();
        }

        public void filterList(ArrayList<AllBlockItem> filteredList) {
            allBlockItemArrayList = filteredList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

anyone can solve this ? Thank you

Comment: try to implement clickListener in onBindViewHolder() method , because here you'll get the correct position

Comment: Can you help me with a code? I getting error move it. thank you

Comment: oh sorry @user9056633 for late reply,

Comment: just remove `int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();` from `onBindViewHolder` method. And make position parameter final in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: how to?........

Comment: use `public void onBindViewHolder(final AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder holder, final int position)` instead of `public void onBindViewHolder(final AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder holder, int position)`

Comment: Its got orange code at final int position. It said 'Do not treat position as fixed; only use unmediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look up later' .what should i do?

Comment: ignore it for now , run the code if possible. if it'll give error then remove `final` from `final int position` and inside the `onBindViewHolder` method just declare `final int pos =position;` and use `AllBlockItem allBlockItem = holder.allBlockItems.get(pos);` instead of `AllBlockItem allBlockItem = holder.allBlockItems.get(position);`

Comment: Still doesnot work dude, it return to the main problem. i think i just remove this feature.. i give up :v . Thanks everyone :). im gonna suicide, just kidding!  . I will try another thing.

Comment: No man, don't give up on this , keep trying , u'll definitely get the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you aren't using the right value of  position.In other words,the position parameter,belongs to the onBindViewHolder() method, is expected to use only inside this method, because it isn't save due to the fact that it might be changed after filter operations.
On the other hand, using getAdapterPosition() ensures that you obtain the right position value.
So,I think if you use  getAdapterPosition() in the right way the problem will be solved.
I've modified your code so that it should work well.Please pay attention to the comments with asterisks.

public class AllBlockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private ArrayList allBlockItemArrayList;
    Context context;

```
public static class AllBlockViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView1;
    public TextView textView2;

    //**** add this field****
    private View itemView;

    ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItems = new ArrayList<AllBlockItem>();
    Context context;

    public AllBlockViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItems) {
        super(itemView);
        this.allBlockItems = allBlockItems;
        this.context = context;

        // ****initialize it here****
        this.itemView = itemView;

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blockImage);
        textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blockTitle);
        textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blockRecipe);
    }

}

public AllBlockAdapter(ArrayList<AllBlockItem> allBlockItems, Context context1) {
    allBlockItemArrayList = allBlockItems;
    context = context1;
}

@Override
public AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.allblock_item, parent, false);
    AllBlockViewHolder allBlockViewHolder = new AllBlockViewHolder(view, context, allBlockItemArrayList);
    return allBlockViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AllBlockAdapter.AllBlockViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AllBlockItem currentItem = allBlockItemArrayList.get(position);

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.textView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.textView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());

    //****set OnClickListener to it here ****
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // ****call getAdapterPosition() on the right ref****
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            AllBlockItem allBlockItem = holder.allBlockItems.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), AllBlockDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("mImageResource", allBlockItem.getImageResource());
            intent.putExtra("mText1", allBlockItem.getText1());
            intent.putExtra("mText2", allBlockItem.getText2());

            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return allBlockItemArrayList.size();
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<AllBlockItem> filteredList) {
    allBlockItemArrayList = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

Comment: this.allBlockItems in holder view onclicklistener got red code.

Comment: In recyclerview.viewholder implement view.onclicklistener got red code too. 
It said Class AllBlockViewHolder must either be declared abstract or implement absctract mrthod onClick(view) in onClickListener

Comment: Sorry, I made these silly mistakes because I was in a hurry.
Please the only thing you have to do is :
1.Omit :" implement view.onclicklistener" you don't need it here.
2.Replace  this.allBlockItems with  holder.allBlockItems.
I've edited the code above so you can copy it.

Comment: i already follow the code that u give but i dont knos why it crash when open the activity, see the update code

Comment: Would you please tell me more details about the error.I usually go to the "android monitor" tab at the left bottom in Android Studio and select error from the spinner then put the string ".java"  in the filter to search where the error exactly occurred because IDE gives us the specific line number in blue so we can click on it to jump into the error in the code.
As the crash happens when you open the activity it is more likely to find something could be helpful in the onCreate() method.
Please pardon if I tell things you already know but I am trying to help you with whatever I know.

Comment: this.context at holder.itemview.onclicklistener got red code. also in this.context.startactivity(intent) got red code. 'Cannot resolve symbol context'

Comment: Again sorry,it's obviously wrong to use"this.context".Please use instead:
"holder.itemView.getContext()" in both situations. I've edited the code again.

Comment: Still doesnot work dude. It show no errors. It looks like when i do search on item it show wrong data at item number 1 until 5 and the right data show when start at item number 6... then i clear the word and i click the item number 1 until 5. It show item data that i was search before. How that happen ? I confused -_-

Comment: Since items aren't updated correctly, I think the problem is with recycling process in general.In other words, there might be something wrong with on of the two methods:
1-onCreateViewHolder
2-onBindViewHolder
I've noticed that  the constructor of AllBlockViewHolder has three parameters, however, I recommend you to use only one which is "View itemView" parameter.It might then work right.
Excuse me, but I'm wondering :Why do you think you need the other two parameters? they seem to be useless.